# NullPointerException in PhoneDirectory programme

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have come across an error in my PhoneDirectory programme. When I try and compile my ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester, It builds successfully however returns the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ArrayPhoneDirectory.addChangeEntry(ArrayPhoneDirectory.java:60)
at ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester.main(ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester.java:17)
Java Result: 1
```

From a little bit of research online, I understand that this means that a variable I am trying to use has been set to null, and that it occurs in my ArrayPhoneDirectory java file in line 60, and in my ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester java file in line 17 (both commented in the code below.). I am still unsure as to which variable it is pointing at and so any help regarding fixing this exception would be much appreciated.

ArrayPhoneDirectory code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayPhoneDirectory implements PhoneDirectory {

private static final int INIT_CAPACITY = 100;
private int capacity = INIT_CAPACITY;

//holds telno of directory entries
private int size = 0;

//Array to contain directory entries
private DirectoryEntry[] theDirectory = new DirectoryEntry[capacity];

//Holds name of data file to be read
private String sourceName = null;

/**
 * Flag to indicate whether directory was modified since it was last loaded
 * or saved.
 */
private boolean modified = false;

// PUBLIC INTERFACE METHODS

public void loadData(String sourceName) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(sourceName).useDelimiter("\\Z");

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        String telno = scan.nextLine();

        add(name, telno);
    }
}

/**
 * find method is called, returning the position in the array of the given
 * name.
 */
public String lookUpEntry(String name) {
    find(name);
    return null;

}

/**
 * for loop that checks every DirectoryEntry inside theDirectory and then
 * checks it against the name and telno given in the parameter, if both are
 * equal, the telno is upda ted, else it is added to theDirectory
 *
 */
public String addChangeEntry(String name, String telno) {
    for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
        if (x.getName().equals(name)) {              //LINE 60
            x.setNumber(telno);
            return x.getNumber();
        } else {
            add(name, telno);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//TO COMPLETE
public String removeEntry(String name) {
    return null;
}

/**
 * A new PrintWriter object is created, and a for loop is used to print the
 * name and number of each DirectoryEntry to the console.
 */
public void save() {
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("directory.txt", true)); 

        for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
            pw.write(x.getName());
            pw.write(x.getNumber());               
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        pw.close();    
    }
}




//Private helper methods

private void reallocate() {
    capacity = capacity * 2;
    DirectoryEntry[] newDirectory = new DirectoryEntry[capacity];
    System.arraycopy(theDirectory, 0, newDirectory,
            0, theDirectory.length);

    theDirectory = newDirectory;
}

private void add(String name, String telno) {
    if (size >= capacity) {
        reallocate();
    }
    theDirectory[size] = new DirectoryEntry(name, telno);
    size = size + 1;
}

private int find(String name) {
    int i = 0;
    for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
        if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}

@Override
public String format() {
    return null;
}



}
```

ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester code:

```
public class ArrayPhoneDirectoryTester {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //creates a new PhoneDirectory
    PhoneDirectory newdir = new ArrayPhoneDirectory();

    newdir.addChangeEntry("Joe Perkins", "999999");  //LINE 17

    System.out.println(newdir);      
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A NullPointerException is thrown when you try to access an object which is null, for example call a method on a null object. In your line 60:

```
x.getName().equals(name)
```

You have two method calls. For this line to throw an NPE, either 'x' is null, or 'x.getName()' is null. If you refactor this onto two separate lines, you will know which:

```
String xName = x.getName();
xName.equals(name)
```

Ideally you should check if they are null:

```
String xName = x.getName();
if(xName == null) { } // do some error handling here
xName.equals(name) ...
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example:

```
public String addChangeEntry(String name, String telno) {

for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
    if (x.getName() == null) {
        log.error("Found a user with no name!!);
        continue; // or throw an exception if this is really bad for you
    }

    if (x.getName().equals(name)) {              //LINE 60
        x.setNumber(telno);
        return x.getNumber();
    } else {
        add(name, telno);
    }
}
return null;

}
```

Comment: I Have refactored onto two lines as you said, however I am still getting the same error returned, please could you explain how this shows which is null? Thanks

Comment: Print out x and x.getName() and tell us which one is null.

Comment: @NickL. Thanks, I just noticed after refactoring onto two lines that it is the x.getName that is null, as the error message changed from line 60 to 61. From here how best should I go about handling the error, would you advise to use try/catch?

Comment: NullPointerException is an unchecked exception, which means that has to do with "programming" errors in a sense. I will post a possible solution as an answer using conditions.

Comment: @JoePerkins - The line number changing is exactly what I was getting at :) It is better to prevent NullPointerExceptions than handle them - before the code that uses the name, check if the name is null. If it is null, you can log an error message, and skip that entry, I will update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

This may be part of your problem (but not the main problem)
You do not need the else statement. Basically your code is only checking the first object and then adding a new object to the directory if it is not a match. Make this change and see What happens
change from:

```
for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
    if (x.getName().equals(name)) {              //LINE 60
        x.setNumber(telno);
        return x.getNumber();
    } else {
        add(name, telno);
    }
}
```

should be

```
DirectoryEntry x;
for (int count =0; count <size; count ++) {
    x = theDirectory[count];
    if (x.getName().equals(name)) {             
        x.setNumber(telno);
        return x.getNumber();
    } 
}
        add(name, telno);
```

edit:
Use a regular for loop. Enhance for:loop is causing your problems. In your array it is going past the number of items you have declared in to the "null" objects in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I hadn't even noticed my useless else statement! I made the change you suggested however I am still getting the same error returned.

Comment: I think you should stick to a regular for-loop. Potentially your enhanced for-loop is going past you initialized objects to the un-initialed section of your array. To confirm this try doing a System.out.println as the first thing in you for loop and see what gets printed out.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a `NullPointerException`, which is an unchecked exception - has to do with "programming errors" in a sense, and not outter facts. You could therefore handle this situation without using exception handling (you are not forced by the compiler to do it).

You can handle this easily by doing checks inside your equality statement, and by using the fact that Java uses **partial evaluation** - if an expression in a statement is enough to assume a safe result, then no other expressions get evaluated:

```
for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
    if (x.getName() != null && x.getName().equals(name)) {             
        x.setNumber(telno);
        return x.getNumber();
    } 
}
//Rest of code goes here....
```

This way, if `x.getName()` equals to null, then the `x.getName().equals(name)` will not become evaluated and you will not have an exception. Of course, you can add more if statements before the equality to make a more special error handling, but this is on your decision to do it.

Comment: I have amended my code to what you proposed, however I am still getting the exact same error message of NullPointerException, as I believe x.getName() is null. How would I go about changing this so it is not null?

Comment: Because of the check x.getName() != null, the exception can't be coming from a null name value. A reason why you get NullPointerException is maybe because x may be null. Please add some prints inside your code (I suggest adding a print inside the loop, to see the x value and maybe attempt to print some data) then inform us of what you get.